# Unable to ping server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, ping, iptables

I have a Linux server that seems to have lost the ability to respond to a ping.. I recently installed Nagios on another system and need to have this Ubuntu server answer up to a ping..  I'm using Webmin's iptables configuration functionality, and it indicates that icmp echo-reply is accepted. I tried flushing the ruleset, and during that time, I was able to ping the server normally. I reapplied the ruleset, and ping-ability went back away.. I've done a pastebin of the actual ruleset that is applied (/etc/iptables.up.rules) and the output of iptables -L when the ruleset is applied..

http://pastebin.com/7AJ2em9P

I'm kind of a noob to iptables, but I'd expect this ruleset to work to my understanding..

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iptables expert and it's been a long time since I had to muck around in iptables, ...but I think you need to add a rule to accept the ping echo-request:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

The rule you have for echo-reply allows your Ubuntu server to ping another server, but won't allow the other server to ping your Ubuntu server. Let me know if this works, please.

Strange, indeed, that it worked before. Did you change the default policy on the input by any chance?

Comment: hmmm... very weird.. the firewall ui in webmin doesnt allow you to enter that as an INPUT chain entry, so I manually added that rules and guess what? ping is back... Don't ask me how it worked before, as I never had that "echo-request" rule in the INPUT chain before.. I've always mamanged the firewall via webmin, as it makes for a secure firewall without being an iptables expert, or at least it did.. puzzling.. Thanks for the help!!